# How to repeat randomised img endlessly on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that render random image without repeating, but it stops working when the array of images has come to an end, my goal is to restart function with another random order of images, so function can work infinite. I've read another questions, but didn't find something appropriate to me case.
Here is html part:

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><img 
        src="1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back"><img src="2.jpg" name="randimg"></div>
    </div>
```

Css (just in case):

```
.card {
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 perspective: 1000px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

.front, .back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: 1s;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.front {
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.back  {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

And JS:

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

Array.from(cards).forEach(function(card) {
 card.addEventListener('click', function() {
Array.from(card.querySelectorAll('.back, .front')).forEach(function(el) {
  ['back', 'front'].forEach(function(s) {
    el.classList.toggle(s)
  });
  });
 });
 });

 var usedImages = {};
 var usedImagesCount = 0;

function pickimg(){
var imagenumber = 3;
var randomnumber = Math.random();
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
images = new Array();
images[0] = "";
images[1] = "3.jpg";
images[2] = "4.jpg";
images[3] = "2.jpg";
var image = images[rand1];
if (!usedImages[rand1]){
    document.randimg.src = images[rand1];
    usedImages[rand1] = true;
    usedImagesCount++;
    if (usedImagesCount === images.length){
        usedImagesCount = 0;
        usedImages = {};
    }
 } else {
    pickimg();
 }
 }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm trying to restart randomising of images, because now, when third image is shown - randomising stops, and I want to restart it in different (another) order.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
let img = [1,2,3,4,5];

function switchImage () {

  for(; ; ){
    let x = Math.random() * 10;
  
    if(typeof img[Math.round(x)] !== 'undefined') {
      img.splice(x, 1);
      break;
    }
    
  }

  console.log(img);
  
  if (img.length > 0){
      setTimeout(() =>  switchImage (),1000);
  }
  

}


switchImage();
```

This is a simplified example where every second the function calls itself again and a new image is picked from the image array. The old image is cut out of the array and the function will stop calling itself when every picture is shown.

Comment: This only works with 2 images, doesn't stop the image from appearing again in a single cycle.

Comment: When there are no images left in array function stops, and my goal is to restart the function I already have, it works, but after displaying third image it stops too, and after clicking on card image doesn't change, and I want it to change again in different order. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
int lastIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*(imagenumber - 1)) + 1;
function pickImg(){
        let imagenumber = 3;
        int currIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*(imagenumber - 1)) + 1;    
        images = new Array();
        images[0] = "2.jpg";
        images[1] = "3.jpg";
        images[2] = "4.jpg";
        if (lastIndex !== currIndex) {      
            document.randimg.src = images[currIndex];
            lastIndex = currIndex;
        }
        else {
            pickImg();
        }
}
```

If you didn't get any image displayed that means you have to deal with when images[index] returns undefined.
Inshort you need to have index in images always equal to some value.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple like this does this work for you? at least it will not give you same number a row

```js
var imgArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // imagine this is your img
var lastImgIndex;

function loadImg() {
  var RandomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArr.length) + 1);
  if (lastImgIndex != RandomIndex) {
    $('span').text(RandomIndex + ' index of img show');
    lastImgIndex = RandomIndex;
  } else {
    loadImg();
  }

}
loadImg();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```